# Replace a text in perl

Tags: perl, file-io

I am trying to find a particular string in file and want to replace that string with another string. Then i want to replace this string in the file also. I am using following code:

```
     open(FILEB,"+<File B (2).txt");
     $hostNameA="Any string\n";
    foreach $lineB(FILEB)
     {
         seek(FILEB,-length($lineB),1);
         $lineB=~s/$hostNameB/$hostNameA/;
         print FILEB $lineB;
     }
```

Basically, my query is how to replace hostNameB ith hostNameA in FileB....

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on linux, there is no need to even open a file and no need to create backup file. Following script should work -

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#Commandline
my $command = "sed -i 's/FOO/BAR/g' /mydir/myfile.txt";

#Execute Command
`$command`;
```

Above script will replace all occurrences of string 'FOO' with 'BAR' in myfile.txt

Answer (score 0):

Write file with same handle will destroy original file.

```
open IN, '<', 'path_to_file' or die $!
open OUT, '>', 'path_to_replaced_file' or die $!;
while (my $line = <IN>) {
    $line =~ s/something/tosomething/g;
    print OUT $line;
}
close OUT;
close IN;
# if you wish, backup old file, and rename new file
```

Comment: what is "path_to_file" and "path_to_replaced_file" ?

Comment: "path_to_file" is your original file, other is replaced file.

Answer (score 0):

How about this 
    `$ perl -pi.bak -e 's/hostNameB/hostNameA/g' "File B (2).txt"`

read the file from "File B (2).txt" and then edit it with regex 's/hostNameB/hostNamea/g'
And back up the original file.